# How might I implement a map of maps in Flink keyed state that supports fast insert, lookup and iteration of nested maps?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'd like to write a Flink streaming operator that maintains say 1500-2000 maps per key, with each map containing perhaps 100,000s of elements of ~100B. Most records will trigger inserts and reads, but I’d also like to support occasional fast iteration of entire nested maps.

I've written a `KeyedProcessFunction` that creates 1500 RocksDb-backed `MapState`s per key, and tested it by generating a stream of records with a single distinct key, but I find things perform poorly. Just initialising all of them takes on the order of several minutes, and once data begin to flow async incremental checkpoints frequently fail due to timeout. Is this is a reasonable approach? If not, what alternative(s) should I consider?

Thanks!

Functionally my code is along the lines of:

```
val stream = env.fromCollection(new Iterator[(Int, String)] with Serializable {
  override def hasNext: Boolean = true

  override def next(): (Int, String) = {
    (1, randomString())
  }
})

stream
  .keyBy(_._1)
  .process(new KPF())
  .writeUsingOutputFormat(...)

class KFP extends KeyedProcessFunction[Int, (Int, String), String] {

  var states: Array[MapState[Int, String]] = _

  override def processElement(
    value: (Int, String),
    ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Int, (Int, String), String]#Context,
    out: Collector[String]
  ): Unit = {
    if (states(0).isEmpty) {
      // insert 0-300,000 random strings <= 100B
    }

    val state = states(random.nextInt(1500))
    // Read from R random keys in state
    // Write to W random keys state
    // With probability 0.01 iterate entire contents of state
    if (random.nextInt(100) == 0) {
      state.iterator().forEachRemaining {
        // do something trivial
      }
    }
  }

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    states = (0 until 1500).map { stateId =>
      getRuntimeContext.getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor[Int, String](stateId.toString, classOf[Int], classOf[String]))
    }.toArray
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: are you using key-partitioned MapState, where the values in those maps are themselves maps? It's not clear how deeply nested things actually are. Also, what's the parallelism, and what sort of disk is RocksDB using for its local volumes?

Comment: I’ve been trying 1500 `MapState` objects for a single key in a `KeyedStream`, in order to avoid inserting entire maps as values.

The parallelism is just 1 right now, as I’m interested in testing the performance of a single task before scaling out.

The disk is NVMe SSD.

Comment: Still not entirely clear on how you have this organized. I believe you have a KeyedStream with only one distinct key of type KEY, and one `MapState<K, V>` (associated with that one `KEY key` from the KeyedStream) holding 1500 entries. For those 1500 entries, how many distinct keys of type K? I'm trying to figure out what kind of strain you are putting on RocksDB. Can you share the code? That would make things much clearer.

Comment: A `KeyedStream` with only one distinct key of type `KEY` but 1500 `MapState<K,V>` associated with that one `KEY`. Say hundreds of thousands of distinct keys of type `K`.

Comment: I've added some example code, let me know if that clarifies things. And thanks!

Comment: Much clearer, but I'm wondering if the 0 in `states(0).isEmpty` is a typo. And I'm wondering if when you iterate over a MapState if you are using the optimized RocksDB MapState iterator.

Comment: No, `if(states(0).isEmpty)` is just to trigger the init code on a first call to `processElement`. And yes, I believe I'm using the optimised iterator, as I just call `state.iterator().forEachRemaining {...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in what you've described that's an obvious explanation for poor performance. You are already doing the most important thing, which is to use `MapState<K, V>` rather than `ValueState<Map<K, V>>`. This way each key/value pair in the map is a separate RocksDB object, rather than the entire Map being one RocksDB object that has to go through ser/de for every access/update for any of its entries.

To understand the performance better, the next step might be to [enable the RocksDB native metrics](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#rocksdb-native-metrics), and study those for clues. RocksDB is quite tunable, and better performance may be achievable. E.g., you can tune for your expected mix of read and writes, and if you are trying to access keys that don't exist, then you should enable bloom filters (which are turned off by default).

The RocksDB state backend has to go through ser/de for every state access/update, which is certainly expensive. You should consider whether you can optimize the serializer; some serializers can be 2-5x faster than others. ([Some benchmarks](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html#performance-comparison).)

Also, you may want to investigate the new spillable heap state backend that is being developed. See https://flink-packages.org/packages/spillable-state-backend-for-flink, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-50%3A+Spill-able+Heap+Keyed+State+Backend, and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12692. Early benchmarking suggest this state backend is significantly faster than RocksDB, as it keeps its working state as objects on the heap, and spills cold objects to disk. (How much this would help probably depends on how often you have to iterate.)

And if you don't need to spill to disk, the the FsStateBackend would be faster still.

Comment: So to confirm, you don't think having 1500 `MapState`s for a given keyed stream is likely a problem in and of itself?

Comment: That's way outside of the norm, so I'm not surprised you've had problems. But could things be configured so that it becomes workable? Not sure.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for going through it with me!